# Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a problem I saw as I was practicing for an exam. It is from a textbook and I don't know how to do it.

The poisson distribution has been used by traffic engineers as a model for light traffic, based on the rationale that if the rate is approximately constant and the traffic is light (so the individual cars move independently of each other), the distribution of counts of cars in a  given time interval or space area should be nearly Poisson. The following table shows the number of right turns during 300 3-min intervals as a specific intersection. Fit a poisson distribution. Comment on the fit by comparing observed and expected counts. It is useful to know that the 300 intervals were distributed over various hours of the day and various days of the week.

n  -------------- Frequency
0  -------------- 14
1  -------------- 30
2  -------------- 36
3  -------------- 68
4  -------------- 43
5  -------------- 43
6  -------------- 30
7  -------------- 14
8  -------------- 10
9  -------------- 6
10 ------------- 4
11  ------------- 1
12  ------------- 1
13+  ------------ 0

Comment: Do you know what is the PDF of poission distribution?
Did you try to fit the data to it?

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: There are many ways.
My favorite is using Matlab fitting toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The expected counts are $\hat{n_i}=\large{e^{-\hat{\lambda}}\cdot \frac{\hat{\lambda}^{x_i}}{x_i!}\cdot 300}$ with $\hat{\lambda}=\frac{292}{75}$

graphical comparison:
[image]